# Transmit parameters to OpenUI app

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I have my Openui5 app. First view is the login page where the user can insert username and password. The server returns a sessionId that I use for the seucessive calls.

Now I want open the app from a company legacy software (where the user has already logged): I want pass to the app the sessionId and store it in the localStorage/sessionStorage.

I don't like pass the sessionId in the url. I would like use another way (cookies? how?)

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you find this? http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/06/29/sapui5-offline-with-jquerysapstorage

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel, and not use openID / OAuth?

Comment: @Qualiture I would like a simple and **fast to implement** solution. Can you show me any example of openId/OAuth?

Comment: It depends a bit on your backend type, but a good starting point is http://oauth.net/code/